# AngularJS: autocomplete made by json from http request

Tags: angularjs, json, autocomplete, httprequest

I'm new to angularjs and wondering my way into it. I want to get a JSON from $http:

```
{"theItems":[{"name":"blah","description":"blah blah"},{...},{...}]}
```

(item.name, item.description) and show the names in an autocomplete input for the user to select.

The JSON is a full object and I want to parse out the name into the autocomplete input but didn't understand how. In other situations I can use ng-repeat to scan the JSON object but that doesn't make sense here.

At the moment nothing really happens with the autocomplete input and I have no idea if something is even retrieved or the problem is that I still didn't parse out the name from the json... please advice.

This is the code for getting the JSON:

```
/*global angular */
angular.module("app").factory('getList', function ($http) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        retrieve: function () {
            $http.get(URL).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This is the code for the autocomplete:

```
/*global angular */
angular.module('app').directive('autocomplete', function ($timeout) {
    'use strict';
    return function ($scope, getList, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: $scope.theList,
            select: function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

this is the controller:

```
/*global angular */
angular.module("app").controller('theController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.theList = function (getList) {
        return getList.retrieve();
    };
}]);
```

this is the html part:

```
Select: <input autocomplete>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rf693c8z/1/
the items in jsfiddle are "handmade", not from the request.

Comment: a plunker would be good

Comment: Yes you need to Put in a plunker .. it will be  pinned to Long Post as you know if any High rep guys see for their rep.. by the way take a look it may helps :- http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/

Comment: I updated the question with jsfiddle link. I saw the example you posted, the array contains only names, in my example, there is an internal array of name/description and I'm not sure how to retrieve only the name

Answer (score 0):

Try the Ui bootstrap type head feature and its directive.

```
<style> .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper { position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 1000; display: none; background-color: #f9f9f9; } .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper > .message { padding: 10px 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; color: #868686; } .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper > .dropdown-menu { position: static; float: none; display: block; min-width: 160px; background-color: transparent; border: none; border-radius: 0; box-shadow: none; } </style>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html"> <a> <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16"> <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span> </a> </script> <script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html"> <div class="custom-popup-wrapper" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" style="display: block;" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}"> <p class="message">select location from drop down.</p> <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox"> <li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}"> <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div> </li> </ul> </div> </script> 
<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
   <h4>Static arrays</h4>
   <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
   <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"> 
   <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
   <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
   <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control"> <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> 
   <div ng-show="noResults"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found </div>
   <h4>ngModelOptions support</h4>
   <pre>Model: {{ngModelOptionsSelected | json}}</pre>
   <input type="text" ng-model="ngModelOptionsSelected" ng-model-options="modelOptions" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"> 
   <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
   <pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
   <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0"> 
   <h4>Custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown</h4>
   <pre>Model: {{customPopupSelected | json}}</pre>
   <input type="text" ng-model="customPopupSelected" placeholder="Custom popup template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" class="form-control"> 
</div>





   angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
              var _selected;
              $scope.selected = undefined;
              $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']; // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously 
              $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
                  return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
                      params: {
                          address: val,
                          sensor: false
                      }
                  }).then(function(response) {
                      return response.data.results.map(function(item) {
                          return item.formatted_address;
                      });
                  });
              };
              $scope.ngModelOptionsSelected = function(value) {
                  if (arguments.length) {
                      _selected = value;
                  } else {
                      return _selected;
                  }
              };
              $scope.modelOptions = {
                  debounce: {
                      default: 500,
                      blur: 250
                  },
                  getterSetter: true
              };
              $scope.statesWithFlags = [{
                          'name': 'Alabama',
                          'flag': '5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Alaska',
                          'flag': 'e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/43px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Arizona',
                          'flag': '9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Arkansas',
                          'flag': '9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arkansas.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'California',
                          'flag': '0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Colorado',
                          'flag': '4/46/Flag_of_Colorado.svg/45px-Flag_of_Colorado.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Connecticut',
                          'flag': '9/96/Flag_of_Connecticut.svg/39px-Flag_of_Connecticut.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Delaware',
                          'flag': 'c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Florida',
                          'flag': 'f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Georgia',
                          'flag': '5/54/Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Hawaii',
                          'flag': 'e/ef/Flag_of_Hawaii.svg/46px-Flag_of_Hawaii.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Idaho',
                          'flag': 'a/a4/Flag_of_Idaho.svg/38px-Flag_of_Idaho.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Illinois',
                          'flag': '0/01/Flag_of_Illinois.svg/46px-Flag_of_Illinois.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Indiana',
                          'flag': 'a/ac/Flag_of_Indiana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Indiana.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Iowa',
                          'flag': 'a/aa/Flag_of_Iowa.svg/44px-Flag_of_Iowa.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Kansas',
                          'flag': 'd/da/Flag_of_Kansas.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kansas.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Kentucky',
                          'flag': '8/8d/Flag_of_Kentucky.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kentucky.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Louisiana',
                          'flag': 'e/e0/Flag_of_Louisiana.svg/46px-Flag_of_Louisiana.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Maine',
                          'flag': '3/35/Flag_of_Maine.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maine.svg.png'
                      }, {
                          'name': 'Maryland',
                          'flag': 'a/a0/Flag_of_Maryland.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maryla
```

Comment: This post is impossible to read, because you've put everything on two lines of code.  Please format it correctly.  You may also consider making this into a [stack snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

The `getList` factory needs to return the httpPromise.

```
/*global angular */
angular.module("app").factory('getList', function ($http) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        retrieve: function () {
            //return promise
            return (
                $http.get(URL).then(function onFulfilled(response) {
                    //return data for chaining
                    return response.data;
                })
            );
        }
    };
});
```